# Delayed job and Mandrill: uninitialized constant Mandrill::API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, mandrill

I have mailer service where users can upload an .xls file with emails and some other user related data to send an email campaign.

I was having some timeout issues since it takes some seconds to process (as I do some validation and configuration for each email to be sent, eg: save records to database, check if an email was sent in the last 30 days, create personalised html code for each email (to create links that contain the email address as a parameter, etc).

After some research, moving this to a [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) seemed reasonable, as suggested in [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised?view=asciicast).  The only problem is that I am having an error that says `uninitialized constant Mandrill::API`, it seems that when I run the job, the call `require 'mandrill'` doesn't work.

I created the task in my model file. Something like this

```
class Mailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :lastname, :name

  def self.send_mail(emails)

    [...a lot of code here...]

    require 'mandrill'
    m = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
    message = {
    :subject=> template.subject,
    :from_name=> template.from_name,
    :from_email=> from + "@" + email_domain,
    :to=>mails,
    :global_merge_vars=> [
      { :name => 'GREETING', :content => template.greeting},
      { :name => 'CONT1', :content => template.message},
      { :name => 'IMAGE', :content => image_url},
          ],
    :html=>email_template,
    :preserve_recipients => false,
    :merge_vars => email_contents,
    }
    sending = m.messages.send message

  end
end
```

from my controller I call `Mailer.send_mails(emails)` and it works just fine, but if I call `Mailer.delay.send_mails(emails)` I get the error. How can I fix this?

I have tried adding `require 'mandrill'` at the beginning of the class, before and after `class Mailer < ActiveRecord::Base` but nothing seems to work

Comment: Let's get the dumb questions out of the way - have you restarted your delayed_job daemon after making those changes? That environment is not self-reloading like Rails in development, AFAIK.

Comment: you were right...I'm sure dumb questions solve 99% of the problems in stackoverflow. I was just restarting the server and not the daemon. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to restart the delayed_job daemon to pick up any code changes. It does not auto-reload like the Rails development environment does.